# Describing the language of a given DFA

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language

[image]I am do not see how I could find the regular expression of the language of the DFA below. It is clear that it has to look something like

$$b \cup (a...)$$

but I do not see how to describe the "lower path". Could you help me?

Comment: $$ 
(b((a\cup b)(a\cup b))^*) \cup (a(a\cup b)((a\cup b)(a\cup b))^*)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $A = \{a,b\}$, your language can be written as $b(A^2)^* + aA(A^2)^*$.